# Is there any way to update UIWebView without getting white background?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and I want to update it's content from time to time. But when I update a content I got white background while data is loading (data include html with few **JavaScripts** inside). Is there any way to do it without delay?

I thought about next solution: I have 2 webViews (webView and backgroundWebView). When I need to update webView I just make a request to backgroundWebView, wait until data loaded and replace webView with backgrounWebView's content. But I do not find any solution how to replace it's content

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

initially in **viewWillAppear** make **UIWebView** hidden and then use webview delegate method as **webViewDidFinishLoad**. In this webview delegate method make your **UIWebView** visible.

**For example**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  webView.hidden=YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  webView.hidden=NO;
}
```

You can also use UIView with any colour or **UIImageView** behind your **UIWebView**. so when your **UIWebview** is getting loading then it will hide and you will see its behind **UIView** or **UIImageview**

Answer (score 0):

You can have dummy `UIView` as a placeholder and put `UIWebView` inside the `UIView` with the same size as the `UIView`, and replace the `UIWebView` using `removeFromSuperview`/`addSubView` whenever  needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with having 2 UIWebViews, but instead of trying to pass the HTML contents of the background view to the foreground view, you should wait for the second webview to finish loading and then move it on top of the first web view with `bringToFront:`.